# Personalized Welcome Messages

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, dreamweaver, message, application.cfc

How do I create a welcome message on my home page with user's name in it?

Dragging dynamic fields from the recordset onto my page does not work:

```
<cfoutput>#Recordset1.Username#</cfoutput>.
```

It keeps using the first username in the table, not the user I am logged in as. Do I have to add something to my Application.CFC page? I'm using ColdFusion, Dreamweaver and MySQL if it makes any difference.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** if you show all the code (how do you log in, how do you query the dataset), it will help us to help you.

Few very general advices for now.

The reason is becasue you select all (or at least more than one) records. When you do the output only once CF shows only first record from dataset. You can check this by looping over the dataset:

```
<cfloop query="Recordset1">
<cfoutput>#Recordset1.Username#</cfoutput><br />
</cfloop>
```

It should show all your records.

As Jason pointed you should select only single record of your user. When you perform login act, save user # (typically primary key, id) in Session scope (say, in *Session.userid*) and use it in queries later like this (I dont know your query, so this is just to show the idea):

```
<cfquery datasource="datasourceName" name="Recordset1">
    SELECT Username FROM users WHERE id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Session.userid#" />
</cfquery>
```

Supposing you have unique id's as PK, you'll get only one record in Recordset1, so your initial output will show correct username.

Comment: ok thaks a heap. Do I have to add into my Application.CFC a this.sessionmanagement='true' or something? Do you know the code i'll have to add in?

Comment: OK heres my codes: 

Heres my code for my Login in page:

<cfif IsDefined("FORM.Username")>
  <cfset MM_redirectLoginSuccess="index.cfm">
  <cfset MM_redirectLoginFailed="login.cfm"> 
  <cfquery  name="MM_rsUser" datasource="cfComment">
  SELECT Username,Password FROM users WHERE Username=<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.Username#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="45"> AND Password=<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.Password#"

Comment: cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="8">
  </cfquery>
  <cfif MM_rsUser.RecordCount NEQ 0>
    <cftry>
    <cflock scope="Session" timeout="30" type="Exclusive">
      <cfset Session.MM_Username=FORM.Username><br />
      <cfset Session.MM_UserAuthorization="">
    </cflock>
    <cfif IsDefined("URL.accessdenied") AND false>
      <cfset MM_redirectLoginSuccess=URL.accessdenied>
    </cfif>
    <cflocation url="#MM_redirectLoginSuccess#" addtoken="no">
    <cfcatch type="Lock"><!--- code for handling timeout of cflock --->
    </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

Comment: </cfif>
  <cflocation url="#MM_redirectLoginFailed#" addtoken="no">
  <cfelse>
  <cfset MM_LoginAction=CGI.SCRIPT_NAME>
  <cfif CGI.QUERY_STRING NEQ "">
    <cfset MM_LoginAction=MM_LoginAction & "?" & XMLFormat(CGI.QUERY_STRING)>
  </cfif>
</cfif>

And for my index pages record set where I'm trying to puy a "Welcome (username)"

<cfquery name="Recordset1" datasource="cfComment">
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.IDUsers 
</cfquery>

Comment: haha. ok, that looks really complicated, it wouldn't let my add it in the question box..oops, sorry. lol

Comment: Oh my... Please try to put the code into the question body. It is not so complex as it seems, see help section. This way it is totally unreadable.

Comment: Yes, you need the to have session management enabled. Also see this really informative and useful man page http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=AppEvents_02.html

Comment: Is this the correct / all the code i need for the application.cfc file to do what I intend:
<cfapplication 
    name = "cfGossip"
    applicationTimeout = #CreateTimeSpan(999, 0, 0, 0)# 
    loginStorage = "session"
    scriptProtect = "all"
    sessionManagement = "yes"
    sessionTimeout = #CreateTimeSpan(999, 0, 0, 0)#
    setClientCookies = "yes" 
    setDomainCookies = "yes>
Thanks.

Comment: Techically yes, but I would not recomment to set such huge expiration periods: 999 days if far from enough, especially for session where it is used to destroy the session when one leaves the site without logging out. Typical session timeout is around 30 minutes (CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)) and application timeout typically discussed in terms of in hours, my personal choise for my needs typically in range from 12 to 48.

Comment: ok. thanks - but if the user is on for more than 12 - 48 hours then will they need to login in again to add a comment - because the session variable will no longer work. So will the automatically be loged off ater 12 - 48 hours?

Comment: 12-48 hours is Application scope lifespan, which should not have anything with user sessions. Specific user information need to be handled using Sessions scope, which should expire quicker because it can be not secure otherwise (imagine someone used your site from public PC and simply closed browser without logging out -- someone can re-open it and access private data).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to add a where clause into your query.

Comment: I just gave it a try, is this what you mean:

<cfquery name="Recordset1" datasource="cfcommentsite">
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.IDUsers 
</cfquery> 

It still does the same thing though, any idea why?

Comment: Youi need a right-hand expression in your where clause.  Assume you store the userid from the database for the logged-in user in session.userid.  SELECT* FROM users WHERE users.IDUsers = <cfqueryparam type="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.userid#">

Comment: I haven't got a session variable set up in my login for the IDUsers - is there some code you know I can put in to make one? cheers.